# Linear-Equation - What is the error in this equation?

Tags: quadratics

I want to know if this equation is wrong?

\begin{align}
    4(x - 3) + 2(x - 1) - 3 &< 10\\
    4x-12 + 2x-1-3 &< 10\\
    4x - 2x &< 10 + 12 + 1 + 3\\
    2x &< 26\\
    x &< 26/2\\
    x &< 13\\
\end{align}

if it is wrong, what is the problem? i tried to solve this equation, but i have doubts about the answer

Comment: This is not an equation.

Comment: $2(x-1)\neq2x-1$. And $4x+2x\neq 4x-2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Inequality, not equation.  As for the math issues:

Second line:  $2(x-1)$ becomes $2x-2$, not $2x-1$.

Third line:  Should be $4x + 2x$, not $4x - 2x$.

There are other errors but they all stem from those two.